# Parsing "eng an Euch geschmiegt"

Tags: preposition

> Wenn ich nur jede Nacht eng **an** Euch geschmiegt einschlafen könnte.

I'm in two minds about whether this "an" comes from "**eng an** Euch" or "**an** Euch **geschmiegt**".

- "eng an jmd." -- "eng an Euch / geschmiegt"
- or: "sich an jmd. schmiegen" -- "an jmd. geschmiegt" -- "eng / an Euch geschmiegt"

Answer (score 1):

I would say it comes from *schmiegen*, because *sich **an** jemanden schmiegen* is a fixed expression (meaning *to nestle up against someone*), whereas *eng* can go with different prepositions, e.g., *eng **an** Euch*, *eng **bei** Euch*, *eng **mit** Euch* or *eng **hinter** Euch*.

Answer (score 0):

The participle to *anschmiegen* would be *angeschmiegt* so the infinitive here is just *schmiegen* or more precisely

> an etwas/jemanden schmiegen

We can supply this with an adverb -*eng*- to describe how we want to snuggle up.

> eng an etwas/jemanden schmiegen

Answer (score 0):

This really is a *Grenzfall*. Maybe because it is constructed with the past participle. Duden has the optional "eng" and a second "an" for non-human-snuggling:

> das Kleid schmiegt sich dem Körper / [eng] **an den Körper an**

I would prefer:

> Wenn ich nur jede Nacht eng an Euch angeschmiegt einschlafen könnte

This sounds a bit like child talk - but then that is a bit the idea.

---

Compare with "sneak **up on** someone", where you also have two prepositions. In German this could be:

> Ich habe mich ganz leise **an** das Tier **heran**geschlichen.

Avoiding the doubling of *an...an*.

---

Duden main example is: **sich an jemanden anschmiegen**

(to snuggle up to somebody)